# Converting date and time into float in python

Tags: python, date

Below is my data set

```
  Date         Time           
  2015-05-13   23:53:00
```

I want to convert date and time into floats as separate columns in a python script.

The output should be like date as `20150513` and time as `235300`

Comment: There is one popular numeric representation of date/time that is the unix timestamp. Is there a reason you want another representation?

Comment: Is this [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object?

Comment: What do you need this for? If your using it to compare then just use `time.time()` or `datetime.total_seconds()` from the datatime or time modules. If you actually need to record the data do what RaymondHettinger did in the answers.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
date = "2015-05-13".replace("-", "")
time = "10:58:56".replace(":", "")
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is to strip the hyphens and colons, [*str.replace()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) should do the job:

```
>>> s = '2015-05-13 23:53:00'
>>> s.replace('-', '').replace(':', '')
'20150513 235300'
```

For mort sophisticated reformatting, parse the input with [*time.strptime()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.strptime) and then reformat with [*time.strftime()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.strptime('2015-05-13 23:53:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> time.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S', t)
'20150513 235300'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datetime you can use [strftime()](http://strftime.org/)

```
your_time.strftime('%Y%m%d.%H%M%S')
```

And if your variables are string, You can use replace()

```
dt = '2015-05-13 23:53:00'
date = dt.split()[0].replace('-','')
time = dt.split()[1].replace(':','')
fl = float(date+ '.' + time)
```